# HTML Tables and Hovering Images and links

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table, hover

I have a client who has an HTML Table layout (ick, I know) that has images in one row and then the corresponding text links in the next row.  The images and text are both separately hyperlinked, styled without underlines (not shown in code here).

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><a href="product1"><img src="productimage1.jpg" /></a></td>
<td><a href="product2"><img src="productimage2.jpg" /></a></td>
<td><a href="product3"><img src="productimage3.jpg" /></a></td>
<td><a href="product4"><img src="productimage4.jpg" /></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="product1">Product1</a></td>
<td><a href="product2">Product2</a></td>
<td><a href="product3">Product3</a></td>
<td><a href="product4">Product4</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I know in CSS, the underline hover can be achieved on the text links.  The question is, is can a user hover over an image (in a table row) and have the corresponding text link (in the next table row) have the underline?  For example, if I hover over "productimage3.jpg", then I'd want the Product3 link to be underlined (and not underlined when the hover is off).  I imagine something can be done with jQuery but I'm kind of a jQuery rookie.

Answer (score 3):

CSS :

```
.hovered {
    text-decoration : underline;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('a').hover(function(){
    $('a[href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]').toggleClass('hovered');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Gs5Q5/1/

Comment: This for some reason didn't work when I inserted it, though it makes logical sense.  I'm still trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
$('img').closest('td').hover(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').next()
      .find('td').eq(this.cellIndex)
      .find('a').css('text-decoration','underline');
},function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').next()
      .find('td').eq(this.cellIndex)
      .find('a').css('text-decoration','none');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6EYpD/3/).

But it'd be a little easier to use classes on the relevant `td`:

```
$('img').closest('td').hover(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').next()
      .find('td').eq(this.cellIndex)
      .addClass('underlines');
},function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').next()
      .find('td').eq(this.cellIndex)
      .removeClass('underlines');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6EYpD/2/).

References:

- jQuery, from the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/).

  - [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
  - [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
  - [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
  - [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
  - [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
  - [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
  - [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/fMtCM/)):

```
$('img').on('mouseover mouseleave', function(e){
    // figure out which table cell we're in
    var column = $(this).closest('td').index();
    // find tr, then jump to the next row
    $(this).closest('tr').next()
        // now find the correct column, then the link inside
        .find('td').eq(column).find('a')
        // add/remove hover class depending on the event
        .toggleClass('hover', e.type === 'mouseover');
});
```

using this css:

```
a:hover, a.hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery you can do something like

```
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <style>
    a{text-decoration: none}
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="image"><a href="product1"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /></a></td>
        <td class="image"><a href="product2"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /></a></td>
        <td class="image"><a href="product3"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /></a></td>
    <td class="image"><a href="product4"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" /></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="title"><a href="product1">Product1</a></td>
        <td class="title"><a href="product2">Product2</a></td>
        <td class="title"><a href="product3">Product3</a></td>
        <td class="title"><a href="product4">Product4</a></td>
    </tr>
    </table>



<script>
    $(function() {

    var items  = $('.image');
    var titles  =  $(".title");
    var index;
    var title;

    $(".image").on("mouseover", function(){
        index = items.index(this);
        title = titles[index];
        $(title).css("text-decoration", "underline");
    });

    $(".image").on("mouseout", function(){
        $(titles).css("text-decoration", "none");
    });

    });

</script>

</body>
```